# Size image by area

Tags: graphics

Sometimes I have to insert many relatively small **different images**, with **different aspect ratio**, which widths must be adjusted one by one in order to look approximately of the same size.

In such cases it would be useful to be able to **size the image by area**, that is choose the area and let LaTeX set image width or height so that **width x height = area** (keeping aspect ratio).

The ideal would be a new command built upon `\includegraphics` **able to accept an `area` parameter** (square root of area would be even better, because in order to get a sense of the size of the area you usually end up in calculating its square root). Such a command, given for example two images `img_a` (having aspect ratio W:H=2:1) and `img_b` (having aspect ratio W:H=2:3), with the following code

```
\includegraphicsbyarea[area=18]{img_a} % suppose area in square centimeters
\includegraphicsbyarea[area=18]{img_b}
\includegraphicsbyarea[area=32]{img_a}
```

would insert:

- `img_a` with width of 6 cm and height of 3 cm (6x3=18, 6:3=2:1)
- `img_b` with width of 3.464 cm and height of 5.196 cm (3.464x5.196=18, 3.464:5.196=2:3)
- `img_a` with width of 8 cm and height of 4 cm (8x4=32, 8:4=2:1)

Would it be possible?

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: Do your images have the same area before you include them?

Comment: @samcarter No, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach not redefining `\includegraphics`. However compared to `scale` option, I cut a branch because I don't have details of `graphicx.sty` in head, so possibly there would be a way to delegate to driver the final rescaling, which I am losing here. Ping @DavidCarlisle.

(I use `xintexpr` but `xfp` of course would do it as well as in Joseph's answer; also, up to some more cumbersome notations one could use only the macros of `xintfrac`, giving a tiny speed-up as expression parsing is skipped).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xintexpr}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{sqrtofarea}{%
    \def\Gin@req@sizes{%
      \edef\Gin@scalex{\xinttheiexpr[5]% round fixed point to 5
                                       % fractional digits
                       \dimexpr#1\relax/
                            sqrt(\Gin@nat@height*\Gin@nat@width)
                       \relax}%
      \let\Gin@scaley\Gin@exclamation
      \Gin@req@height\Gin@scalex\Gin@nat@height
      \Gin@req@width\Gin@scalex\Gin@nat@width
      }%
  \@tempswatrue}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=2cm]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=3cm]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=4cm]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=5cm]{example-image-a}

\newbox\mybox
Equality only expected up to 5 digits of precision due to intrinsic
limitations of graphicx computations.

\setbox\mybox\hbox{\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=2cm]{example-image-a}}%

\xinttheiiexpr\ht\mybox*\wd\mybox\relax
?=
\xinttheiiexpr\dimexpr2cm\relax*\dimexpr2cm\relax\relax\ (4cm$^2$)

\setbox\mybox\hbox{\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=5cm]{example-image-a}}%

\xinttheiiexpr\ht\mybox*\wd\mybox\relax
?=
\xinttheiiexpr\dimexpr5cm\relax*\dimexpr5cm\relax\relax\ (25cm$^2$)
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The sentence at bottom of image must be amended: in TeX all dimensions are integer multiples of 1sp. When we set the area **square root** as key, we automatically limit the achievable precision of the *area*. For example `5cm` 
internally in TeX gives 9323399sp, hence a square equal to 86925768913201 as in image above. The previous square is 86925750266404 and the next one is 86925787560000, so they diverge in the 7th digit already and we can never overcome that possible imprecision when comparing a square with a produce height times width. Above we observe discrepancy already in 5th digit so the sentence is probably not completely wrong, but I felt I needed to add this mathematical precision.

---

Here is same with `xfp` (basically copied from Joseph's way of using it):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfp}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{sqrtofarea}{%
    \def\Gin@req@sizes{%
      \edef\Gin@scalex{\fpeval{#1/sqrt(\Gin@nat@height*\Gin@nat@width)}}%
      \let\Gin@scaley\Gin@exclamation
      \Gin@req@height\Gin@scalex\Gin@nat@height
      \Gin@req@width\Gin@scalex\Gin@nat@width
      }%
  \@tempswatrue}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=2cm]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=3cm]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=4cm]{example-image-a}

\includegraphics[sqrtofarea=5cm]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

About this:

- no wrapping of `#1` in `\dimexpr #1\relax` needed here; `xintexpr` could easily be extended to recognize `cm`, `in`, `pt`, etc ... units so that e.g. `2cm` is understood automatically, but the problem is that it would then do an exact conversion to a fractional number of `sp` units, whereas TeX process is more complex than simply using a proportionality factor and proceeds with rounding and truncating in various directions at various stages; so using exact conversion factor means not doing same operations as TeX itself. For this reason, no such units are defined yet in `xintexpr` and user must go via `\dimexpr #1\relax`; the `xintexpr` parser will apply `\number` to this, triggering TeX's own way to convert dimensional units.
- I am not expert in `xfp` so I don't know if sometimes such computation could result in a scientific notation which would break TeX later; in the `xintexpr` solution I applied a transformation to fixed point value with 5 fractional digits. I don't know how one does that in `xfp` and whether it could be needed here in some cases. In the MWE above it works fine.

Comment: It seems that I wrote too early about "optimal" solutions. Your solution as far as I understand adds the `sqrtofarea` option (nice name, by the way) to standard `includegraphics` (which is better than adding a new command). I also tested the `sqrtofarea` option together with the standard `angle` option of `includegraphics` ans it works, whereas if I add the same `angle` option when using the command `includegraphicsbyarea` of other solutions I get an error.

Comment: I think @DavidCarlisle should be pinged about correct way to add this option to `\includegraphics`. Good to hear it works with `angle` option. I added some mathematical comment at bottom of answer.

Comment: I think that `sqrtofarea` should definitively become a standard option of `includegraphics`. Scaling by area is the best way of sizing many images different in size and aspect ratio so that they look approximately of the same size.

Comment: unfortunately even with e-TeX's `\numexpr, \dimexpr`, it requires some work to avoid arithmetic overflows when implementing computations at low-level. Already graphicx/graphics has some extra code for obtaining ratio of two lengths which works well enough in 99.99% of real life situations, and is cleverly compact, but sqrtofarea requires extra implementation effort as it seems at least square root must be handled. Naturally graphicx will never load package like xint and all its unneeded macros. Perhaps in future it will have xfp automatically, then of course, sqrtofarea becomes feasible.

Comment: Maybe `sqrt(\Gin@nat@height)*sqrt(\Gin@nat@width)` would help in avoiding overflow? (I barely understand what you mean, sorry if I suggested something stupid).

Comment: @mmj, the `sqrt` doesn't exist by itself, it needs implementation. The `xfp` for example with implements almost IEEE-754 floating point, so no overflow in real life (16 digits precision). Or `xint` which works in arbitrary precision. Overflows arises in the core TeX arithmetic which limits dimensions to 30bits and integers to 31bits. This is the infamous "dimension too large" thing one sometimes encounters with TikZ when it implements all via TeX dimension native arithmetic.

Answer (score 8):

Scaling to an area is an unusual request: normally one knows the target height or width. The following takes the image and scales such that the area is that given in the optional argument, interpreted in square centimetres:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfp}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Garea}{area}{\def\Garea@area{#1}}
\define@key{Garea}{areaunit}{\def\Garea@unit{#1}}
\define@key{Gin}{area}{} % So we can pass through easily
\define@key{Gin}{areaunit}{}
\newcommand*{\Garea@area}{}
\newcommand*{\Garea@unit}{cm}
\newcommand{\includegraphicsbyarea}[2][]{%
  \setkeys{Garea}{#1}%
  \ifx\Garea@area\@empty
    \gdef\Garea@scale{scale = 1}%
  \else
    \begingroup
      \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
      \xdef\Garea@scale{scale =
        \fpeval{sqrt((\Garea@area * 1 \Garea@unit * 1 \Garea@unit)
          /(\the\ht0 * \the\wd0))}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\Garea@scale,#1]{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includegraphicsbyarea[area=100]{example-image-a}
\includegraphicsbyarea[area=100,areaunit=pt]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

It still applies any options to the graphic: I've ordered such that the area scale is *first*, but one might want to put it *last*.

---

An alternative interface uses the square root of the area of the image: conveniently this has units we can work with directly

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfp}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Garea}{sqrtarea}{\def\Garea@sqrtarea{#1}}
\define@key{Gin}{sqrtarea}{}
\newcommand*{\Garea@sqrtarea}{}
\newcommand{\includegraphicsbyarea}[2][]{%
  \setkeys{Garea}{#1}%
  \ifx\Garea@diag\@empty
    \gdef\Garea@scale{scale = 1}%
  \else
    \begingroup
      \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
      \xdef\Garea@scale{scale =
        \fpeval{\Garea@sqrtarea /(sqrt(\the\ht0 * \the\wd0))}}%
    \endgroup
  \fi
  \expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\Garea@scale,#1]{#2}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includegraphicsbyarea[sqrtarea = 5cm]{example-image-a}
\includegraphicsbyarea[sqrtarea = 10cm]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

(See the [answer by mmj](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447189) for an alternative name for the key.)

Comment: Your answer is clean and works well, but I would like to choose the unit of measure of the area. To obtain that it might be helpful using as parameter the square root of area instead of area. I think that using the square root of area is better, because to get a sense of the area you usually end up calculating the square root (I updated my question to underline that).

Comment: I've added a follow up with an improved (IMHO) version of your solution. If you agree, please consider replacing your actual solution with that one, and I will delete the follow up, just for clarity towards future readers.

Comment: @mmj I've added a version using the diagonal as the scaling determinant: that has a square-root relationship to area, and has units, and has a clear name :)

Comment: @mmj You'd be better to post your answer code as an answer, rather than edit it into the question. The site structure works best that way: as it stands, its a bit confusing.

Comment: Diagonal is a nice name and of course varies linearly with the width and height of an image, but it does not vary linearly when the aspect ratio changes, and the command is supposed to deal with images having different aspect ratios. What you call *diagonal* is actually the same parameter I used to modify your code, it is the **square root of the area**. Calling it *diagonal* is misleading the user because he/she might think that a 16x1 image and a 4x4 image will have the same diagonal, whereas they will have the same area (16) but very different diagonals, about 16 and 5.66 respectively.

Comment: @mmj It's the diagonal of the square image of the same area ... in any case, this is very much something for 'local' use, so the name of the key us down to you.

Comment: Actually it is the side of the square image of equal area, not the diagonal.

Comment: `\setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics[draft,#1]{#2}}` with added `draft` option perhaps brings some efficiency gain.

Comment: @jfbu Not really, I suspect: the images are cached anyway, at least in pdfTeX/LuaTeX, so we only actually include it in the PDF once anyway ...

Comment: I tested replicating 10000 inclusions (in an `\hbox`) of a local copy of `example-image-a.pdf` as `foo.pdf` in source repertory with and without `draft` option for vanilla `\includegraphics` and I get circa 1.15s with draft option and 1.55s without... and for some reason that I ignore simply adding `\usepackage{xfp}` to my test file raises this to 1.25s versus 1.66s. (my test file is simply with usepackage graphics and xintkernel for xintreplicate, but l3benchmark will be better surely than my pdfresettimer/pdfelapsedtime). No idea why an extra `\usepackage{xfp}` modifies the timings...

Comment: .. if I replace `\usepackage{xfp}` by `\usepackage{xintexpr}` I get also time increase! My timings of course do not include preamble loading, so this surprises me. I get an even stronger effect with `\usepackage{tikz}` so I suspect something with the hash table or other TeX internals. Again I time 4 times in one run: `reset 10000 repeats elapsedtime, reset 10000 repeats then elapsed time, ..., ...` alternating with and without `draft`. The more I load packages in preamble, the slower the execution....

Answer (score 6):

## Update 3

This is the last revision, I promise.

The only change is the use of `pgfmath.sty` in place of `fp-eval.sty` which, in turn, required a little special handling to avoid `dimension too large` errors. As well, the use of `pgfmath.sty` allowed for considerable simplification. The new output is identical to the old.

%===8><-----%

I was unhappy with the way that I left the \scaletoarea macro. It has been altered to be, hopefully, a little more user-friendly. I have made it possible to use the options to `\includegraphics` for all of the macros. Take a look at the examples.

%===8><---%

I take it that you want all of the graphics to have the same *area* regardless of the *aspect ratio.* The following code does that.
There are two approaches outlined here.

The first scales subsequent graphics based on the size of the first graphic Use `\fpic` for the *first* graphic; using `\spic` for the subsequent graphics will size them to have the same area as the first graphic. Use the options to `\fpic` (the same as those to `\includegraphics`) to size the first graphic accordingly.

Second, if you know the target area, you can use `\scaletoarea{<unitless area>}{<linear unit of area>}{<name of graphic>}`. For example, if you were to scale a graphic, `foo`, so that it is 5 square inches in area, you would write: `\scaletoarea{5}{in}{foo}`. Any of the units recognized by TeX can be used.

```
    \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx,calc,pgfmath} 
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\newlength\fpicw
\newlength\fpich
\newlength\spicw
\newlength\spich
\newsavebox{\firstpic}
\newsavebox{\nextpics}
\newlength{\targetarea}

%% \fpic[<options to \includegraphics>]{<name of graphic>}
\newcommand{\fpic}[2][]{% First picture, use \includegraphics, and options
    \sbox{\firstpic}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}% 
    \settoheight{\fpich}{\usebox{\firstpic}}% 
    \settowidth{\fpicw}{\usebox{\firstpic}}%
    \usebox{\firstpic}%
} 

%% \spic[<options to \includegraphics>]{<graphic name>}
\newcommand{\spic}[2][]{% Second and succeeding pictures
    \sbox{\nextpics}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}%
    \settoheight{\spich}{\usebox{\nextpics}}% 
    \settowidth{\spicw}{\usebox{\nextpics}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\scaling}{sqrt((\fpicw/\spicw)*(\fpich/\spich))}%
    \scalebox{\scaling}{\usebox{\nextpics}}% 
    \typeout{**The scaling (#2) = \scaling}% Comment-out if not needed
}

%% \scaletoarea[<options to \includegraphics>]{<unitless area>}{<unit of area (linear)>}{<graphic name>}
\newcommand{\scaletoarea}[4][]{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mytmp}{sqrt(#2)}%
    \setlength{\targetarea}{\mytmp #3}%
    \sbox{\nextpics}{\includegraphics[#1]{#4}}%
    \settoheight{\spich}{\usebox{\nextpics}}% 
    \settowidth{\spicw}{\usebox{\nextpics}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\scaling}{sqrt((\targetarea/\spicw)*(\targetarea/\spich))}%
    \scalebox{\scaling}{\usebox{\nextpics}}% 
    \typeout{++The scaling (#4) = \scaling}% Comment-out if not needed
}

%% \scaletoareab[<options to \includegraphics>]{<square root of desired area>}{<name of graphic>}
\newcommand{\scaletoareab}[3][]{%
    \setlength{\targetarea}{#2}%
    \sbox{\nextpics}{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}%
    \settoheight{\spich}{\usebox{\nextpics}}% 
    \settowidth{\spicw}{\usebox{\nextpics}}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\scaling}{sqrt((\targetarea/\spicw)*(\targetarea/\spich))}%
    \scalebox{\scaling}{\usebox{\nextpics}}% 
    \message{++The scaling (#3) = \number\scaling}%
}

\begin{document} 

\fpic[width=1.25in]{Peppers}\spic{Pasta}\spic{OldImage}\spic{BethanyDrawing}

\scaletoarea{3}{in}{Peppers}\scaletoarea{12}{cm}{Pasta}\scaletoarea{2}{in}{OldImage}\scaletoarea{61}{pc}{BethanyDrawing}

\scaletoarea[width=0.5in,height=3in,keepaspectratio=false]{3}{in}{Peppers}
\scaletoareab[width=0.5in,height=3in,keepaspectratio=false]{1.732050807568877in}{Peppers}

\end{document}
```

[image: Scaling to area examples]

Comment: My math was wrong for `\scaletoarea`. The first argument to `\scaletoarea` should be the **square root** of the desired area. Made the correction in the code listing.

Comment: I have modified my original answer to modify how `\scaletoarea` works.

Comment: I tested the previous version of your `scaletoarea` command and it worked well, but above all I liked the use of square root of area as parameter instead of area. In fact using the square root of area is better, because to get a sense of the area you have in any case to calculate the square root. And you save a parameter in comparison to the new current version that needs an additional parameter for the unit of measure. Please consider restoring the use of square root of area as parameter for `scaletoarea` command.

Comment: I'm a little tied up now, but I will get to it later today or tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @mmj Check now. The macro (last one in the code) is `\scaletoareab[<options to \includegraphics>]{<square root of desired area>}{<name of graphic>}`. Included example and output.

Comment: Great, it works like before, thanks. I think that the current `scaletoareab` command is by far the most useful of all your commands, it would deserve a dedicated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an MCVE that fulfills your requirements provided th. I have also added commented the code and added a full explanation with regards to the logic of the program.

Sample output:
[image: Output]

Now the explanation:

[image: Explanation]

The code!:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx, color}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calculator}         % Very important package. Provides
                                % basic mathematical operations like
                                % addition, subtracting, multiplying
                                % dividing, rounding, truncating, and
                                % finding the GCD (greatest common divisor).
\usepackage{caption, amsmath, amssymb}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\getlength}[1]{\strip@pt#1}
\makeatother

% For the area, and ratio (width:height) = (\xRatio:\yRatio)
\newlength{\areaGiven}
\newlength{\xRatio}
\newlength{\yRatio}

% Accepts 4 argments: area, width ratio, height ratio, and name of image (respectively).
\newcommand*{\adjustImage}[4]{%
  \setlength\areaGiven{#1 cm}
  \setlength\xRatio{#2 cm}
  \setlength\yRatio{#3 cm}

  \noindent Given information~~~~~~~~~~~: \textbf{area} = #1cm, 
  \textbf{ratio} $(width:height) = #2:#3$.

  % Convert the unit from pt to cm. Note, 1pt = 0.0352778cm.
  % If you really care about exact numbers, 1.0000008pt = 0.035277806cm.
  % If inches is the unit to focus on, then change 0.0352778 to 0.0138889.
  \MULTIPLY{\getlength{\areaGiven}}{0.0352778}{\areaInCm}
  \MULTIPLY{\getlength{\xRatio}}{0.0352778}{\xRatioInCm}
  \MULTIPLY{\getlength{\yRatio}}{0.0352778}{\yRatioInCm}

  \noindent Converting from pt to cm : \textbf{area} = \areaInCm cm,
  \textbf{ratio} $(width:height) = \xRatioInCm cm:\yRatioInCm cm$.

  % Keep in mind that there will be rounding errors. The answer
  % we will obtain is a decimal answer. Since pixels are atomic, we need to 
  % truncate (or round) the decimal values to secure a whole number.
  % I used the TRUNCATE command, you can comment the next three line and 
  % uncomment the ROUND commands if you want to round.
  \TRUNCATE[0]{\areaInCm}{\areaInCm}
  \TRUNCATE[0]{\xRatioInCm}{\xRatioInCm}
  \TRUNCATE[0]{\yRatioInCm}{\yRatioInCm}
  % OR use round instead. It is better for images with areas 100+.
  % \ROUND[0]{\areaInCm}{\areaInCm}
  % \ROUND[0]{\xRatioInCm}{\xRatioInCm}
  % \ROUND[0]{\yRatioInCm}{\yRatioInCm}

  \noindent After truncating~~~~~~~~~~~~~: \textbf{area} = \areaInCm,
  \textbf{ratio} $(width:height) = \xRatioInCm cm:\yRatioInCm cm$.

  % The following are the steps of find the result mathematically.
  % This is explained in details at the end of the docmument.
  \MULTIPLY{\xRatioInCm}{\yRatioInCm}{\k}   % 1) finds (a*b) in ak*bk = area.
  \DIVIDE{\areaInCm}{\k}{\k}                % 2) finds (area/(a*b)) in k^2 = (area/(a*b)).
  \SQUAREROOT{\k}{\kFinal}                  % 3) finds of k in k = sqrt((area/(a*b))).
  \MULTIPLY{\xRatioInCm}{\kFinal}{\x}       % 4) multiplies the x-ratio by k.
  \MULTIPLY{\yRatioInCm}{\kFinal}{\y}       % 5) multiplies the y-ratio by k.

  \noindent \textbf{Final dimensions are}~~~: 
  \textbf{width} = \x cm, \textbf{height} = \y cm.

  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width = \x cm, height = \y cm]{#4} % 6*3 cm
    \captionof{figure}{
      \textbf{area} = #1cm, \textbf{ratio} 
      $(width:height) = #2:#3$ $\longrightarrow$
      \textbf{width} = \x cm, \textbf{height} = \y cm.
    }
  \end{center}  
}

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{Example A:}}\newline
  \adjustImage{18}{2}{1}{example-image-a} % area = 18cm, ratio (width:height) = 2:1
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{Example B:}}\newline
  \adjustImage{18}{2}{3}{example-image-b} % area = 18cm, ratio (width:height) = 2:3
  \textcolor{red}{\textbf{Example C:}}\newline
  \adjustImage{32}{2}{1}{example-image-c} % area = 32cm, ratio (width:height) = 2:1
  % Maximum area is 575 units! 
  % \adjustImage{575}{2}{1}{TestImage.png} % area = 575cm, ratio (width:height) = 2:1

  \newpage
  \newgeometry{margin=1in}

  % Here is the explanation of the logic.
  \noindent\textbf{Explaining the logic with an example:}\newline
  The logic is a simple mathematical manipulation.\newline
  First, we need our three variables, 
  the total area we will call $area$ and the ratio $x : y$.\newline\newline
  Let $area = 18$ and the ratio $x : y = 2 : 1$.\newline
  We know that $x \times y = area$ or in other words, $2x \times y = 18$.\newline
  For simplicity, let's only use one variable, $k$. Substitute $k$ \newline
  in our previous equation for both $x$ and $y$, $2k \times k = 18$.\newline
  Solve for $k$:
  \begin{align*} 
    2k \times k &= 18\\
    2k^{2}      &= 18\\
    k^{2}       &= 9\\
    k           &= 3
  \end{align*}
  Now, we multiply $k = 3$ in our original ratio $x : y = 2 : 1$.\newline
  Hence, our desired ratio is :
  \begin{align*} 
    x : y &= 2(k) : 1(k)\\
    x : y &= 2(3) : 1(3)\\
    x : y &=    6 : 3\\
  \end{align*}\bigskip

  % Formal definition.
  \noindent\textbf{Formal definition:}\newline
  Let $area$ represent the total area of the image and the ratio $x : y$ respectively
  represent the $width : height$ of the image.\newline
  Find a value $k$ such that $area = kx \times ky$:
  \begin{align*} 
    area &= (k)x \times (k)y\\
    area &= k^{2}\times (xy)\\  % Step 1 (in the preamble) stores x*y.
    \frac{area}{xy} &= k^{2}\\  % Step 2 (in the preamble) stores area/(x*y)
    \sqrt{\frac{area}{xy}} &= k\\% Step 3 (in the preamble) stores sqrt((area/(x*y)))
  \end{align*}
  Now, multiply $k$ by the our ratio given, $x : y$. % Steps 4 and 5 (in the preamble).
  \[kx : ky\]
  Which yields to $area = kx \times ky$. \hfill $\blacksquare$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer, maybe my question wasn't clear enough, please see the update.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it out.

Comment: You say that my desire is not achievable, but if you know an area A = W x H and an aspect ratio R = W / H, you can definitively find unique values for width W and height H, which is what I'm asking.

Comment: Did you read all the post? If you elimanate the real values then sure, you can find a ratio assuming that W and H are not at the lowest ratio form, like W=2 and H=8... which you can have a reduced ratio of 1:4.... Now, if your ratio is 4:5, you cannot reduce it further because it's in the lowest form already... if you want you can enter the real values and divide it by 2 to obtain 2:2.5 but then you entered the real values where there are infinite solutions. You can divide by 2 or 3 or 4 or even 10000000^10000.... all are valid decimal ratios.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The aspect ratio of an image is always a rational number. You cannot "reduce" the ratio because width x height must be equal to a **given and arbitrary** number, the area. My previous comment explain the simple math behind the question.

Comment: What are the information that we already have? Only area?

Comment: Area and, of course, aspect ratio of image. Two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: I have posted yet another approach. I hope I nailed it.

Comment: You almost got the point. The command `\adjustImage` should accept only 2 parameters (area and image file), not 4, because the aspect ratio information should be retrieved from the image; if you fix this you have answered to the question. You could take inspiration from other answers and try to improve them.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}% only needed if you want captions
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}

\bigskip
\makebox[\linewidth]{% only needed if the textwidth is smaller than the images
 \includegraphics[width=6cm,height=3cm,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-b}
 \includegraphics[width=3.464cm,height=5.196cm,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-b}
 \includegraphics[width=8cm,height=4cm,keepaspectratio=false]{example-image-b}%
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your answer, maybe my question wasn't clear enough, please see the update.

Comment: then use `[width=...,height=...,keepaspectratio=false]{image}`.  see edited answer

Comment: I don't want to change the aspect ratio of images, I want a LaTeX command which use the aspect ratio R = W / H of image AND an area parameter A chosen by me, to calculate the width W and height H of image so that W x H = A and W / H = R.